# How i do lazy loading at vue-form-wizard with Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have "vue-form-wizard": "0.8.4" and i want the lazy-loading for tabs.
Try was this but not work

```
<tab-content
  :lazy-loading="true"
  :title="$t('stock.level')"
>
 <levels :model-data="modelData" />
</tab-content>
```

Thats my code:

```
<form-wizard
      shape="square"
      :finish-button-text="$t('Create')"
      :next-button-text="$t('next')"
      :back-button-text="$t('previos')"
      @on-complete="showModal"
    >
      <tab-content
        :title="$t('stock.generalinformation')"
      >
          <general :model-data="modelData.product" :using-add-multiple="true" />
      </tab-content>
  
      <tab-content
        :title="$t('stock.level')"
      >
        <levels :model-data="modelData" />
      </tab-content>
    </form-wizard>
```